# why a c program spends so much time in kernel mode?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, virtual-machine

I use *time* command to measure execution time of a c program and I see that it spends so much time in kernel mode (although I expect it to run mostly in user mode). I don't know why, and I don't have any clue where to search for the problem.

this is an example:

```
real  0m44.548s
user  0m19.956s
sys   1m19.944s
```

These are information about the test program. it is *streamcluster* from [parsec benchmark tools](http://wiki.cs.princeton.edu/index.php/PARSEC#Streamcluster).

- Application domain: data mining
- Data sharing: low
- Data exchange: medium
- Parallelization model: data-parallel
- Contains many pthread_mutexes and pthread_conditions
- CPU bound
- Little memory allocations or writing to files

I run this program on a virtual machine.

Comment: It could spend more time in kernel for any number of reasons. Your question is unanswerable. Post the relevant code.

Comment: @BlueMoon could waiting on a condition be one of them? the code is more than a thousand lines, I'm looking for some ideas.

Comment: No, waiting on a condition doesn't count towards neither user time nor sys time, because processes waiting for a condition are not runnable (unless they wait by polling). This question is extremely vague and consequently hard to answer without looking at the relevant code. I suggest you use something like [gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/) to start looking for bottlenecks.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves actually, there is a bottleneck on one of the conditions, is it relevant?

Comment: What for you is time spent in kernel is mostly time used to run other threads (not only keep the kernel running).

Comment: Using the Linux `perf` tool you can find out where the time is being spent in the kernel (`perf record -g <program>` then `perf report`).

Comment: @Frankie_C would you explain more please?

Comment: On any decent OS the system executes many threads concurrently (i.e you can use the browser while writing on a text editor or playing a movie in another window). The OS switch execution threads of all these activities. If you record time of execution and time of idle **of your program** doesn't mean that during idles the CPU is waste in the kernel. It will probably run a slice for each active thread, some OS keep duties and then come back to your program.

Comment: @Frankie_C: The system time reported by the `time` command is kernel time *accounted to the program you are running*.  It's not idle time or time running other threads - it's time that the kernel is running on behalf of your program, more or less.

Comment: @caf You're right. I should have been really sleepy to don't realize he was talking of `time` command! :-(